# How to prevent apps auto-reinstalling?

Tags: google-play-store, 5.1-lollipop, usb-debugging, application-autoupdate

Almost every time I connect my phone to my PC apps auto-reinstall in the background. I say "auto-reinstall" rather than "auto-update" because the versions aren't changing.

Auto-update is disabled but `logcat` indicates the apps are being auto-updated:

`root@android:/ # logcat -v long *:V | grep -C 1 "Requesting install"`


`[ 05-05 13:30:27.732  5687: 5687 I/Finsky   ]
[1] khl.a(2): Requesting install request=package_name=com.example.app, version=123, priority=3,`**reason=auto_update**`, account_name=[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx], type=0, constraints=((REQ_CHARGING, REQ_GEARHEAD_PROJECTION_OFF, NETWORK=UNMETERED, PROVISIONING_STATE=PROVISIONED, ),)`

[image: no auto-update]

Why does this happen? How do I stop it?

Answer (score 1):

This is hardly a satisfactory solution, but I've taken to freezing the Google Play Store app (`pm disable com.android.vending`) except for when I explicitly need to use it (I also use [Yalp Store](https://labs.xda-developers.com/store/app/com.github.yeriomin.yalpstore) and [APKGrabber](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-apkgrabber-release-apkupdater-t3907372) for updating apps).

Comment: +1 I followed same route after I couldn't bear the annoyances from Google play :)